# How to delete a row in 3 tables with same query in My sql

Tags: mysql

delete from tbl_savedgroupmessage, tbl_savedusermessage, tbl_message where  tbl_savedgroupmessage.msgid= tbl_savedusermessage.msgid= tbl_message.msgid= '876'

I tried this but it throws error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DELETE t1, t2, t3
FROM
  tbl_savedgroupmessage t1
JOIN tbl_savedusermessage t2
  ON t1.msgid = t2.msgid
JOIN tbl_message t3
  ON t1.msgid = t3.msgid
WHERE
  t3.msgid = '876'
```

**Example:**

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
  id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE table_b (
  id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table_a VALUES 
  (2),
  (3),
  (1);

INSERT INTO table_b VALUES 
  (2),
  (5),
  (1);

DELETE t1, t2
FROM
  table_a t1
JOIN table_b t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE
  t1.id = 1;


SELECT * FROM table_a;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    2 |
|    3 |
+------+

SELECT * FROM table_b;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    2 |
|    5 |
+------+
```

Comment: Does this really work? Can you provide a link to the documentation?

Comment: Sometimes the documentation is poor.

Comment: I agree, MySQL documentation is the worst I've seen, but can you provide a little script demonstrating that this actually works? I don't run MySQL, unfortunately.

Comment: What is the t1, t2 I want to delete the whole record

Comment: +1 to mysql for allowing delete from multiple tables. This is not allowed in Sybase or MS.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html It's written there... Unfortunatly there is no anchor - but it's at the bottom of the page.

Comment: This works, and is documented (properly with two examples) here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html. But... in most situations I would prefer to use three single statements, one for each table.

Comment: @Icarus documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html
search for "multiple tables"

Comment: +1 @Devart I just did search on MySQL docs and found that your statement is true. I've upvoted this answer. This is the best answer for what OP wants but *I still think that setting constraints appropriately is the right way to do it. That's perhaps why most DBMS don't support this.*

Comment: @Mr.Mindor Thanks. I found it too and updated my answer stating that I am wrong in thinking that MySQL does not support this. I've upvoted this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot delete from three tables in one query in that manner. delete is an operation that targets a single table.

```
delete from tbl_savedgroupmessage where msgid = '876';
delete from tbl_savedusermessage where msgid = '876';
delete from tbl_message where msgid = '876'
```

If there are constraints in place referencing one table to the other, you will have to change the order. If you need these all to fail or succeed together, put them in a transaction and roll back on the failure of any.

Edit: While true with ANSI compliant sql and in T-SQL, it is actually possible to delete from multiple tables in one statement in mysql. guess you learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a joined DELETE command or delete the rows seperately.

```
DELETE FROM
    tbl_message, tbl_savedgroupmessage, tbl_savedusermessage
LEFT JOIN
    tbl_savedgroupmessage ON (tbl_message.msgid = tbl_savedgroupmessage.msgid)
LEFT JOIN
    tbl_savedusermessage ON (tbl_message.msgid = tbl_savedusermessage.msgid)
WHERE
   tbl_message.msgid = 876;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to join the tables together in order to delete it together. Also, add the columns you would like to delete.
for example:

`delete tbl_savedgroupmessage.*, tbl_savedusermessage.*

from tbl_savedgroupmessage, tbl_savedusermessage

where tbl_savedgroupmessage.msgid = tbl_savedusermessage.msgid

and tbl_savedgroupmessage.msgid = '876'`

Comment: THis one doesn't delete tbl_message table I want to do everything in single query